# How to do sequential deployment on servers when we have multiple servers under environments in Azure Devops using yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can someone tell me a way to do sequential deployment on a number of servers added in ABC-DEV environment in Azure Devops using yml - not the classic way?

Comment: It's better to ask user to provide more details instead of giving -1

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it could be helpful to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the sequence of the deployment jobs running in the same environment but on different servers(VM resources), you can explicitly define which server(VM) the deployment job should be running on and define each deployment job name and its **dependency**.

You may also consider using [each expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword) to simplify the YAML syntax. Kindy take the following sample YAML for a reference.

[image]

```
parameters:
- name: Servers
  type: object
  default:
  - ServerName: Server0
    Dependency: []
  - ServerName: Server1
    Dependency: DeploymentJobOnServer0
  - ServerName: Server2
    Dependency: DeploymentJobOnServer1

stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
  - ${{ each Server in parameters.Servers }}:
    - deployment: DeploymentJobOn${{ Server.ServerName }}
      dependsOn: ${{ Server.Dependency }}
      environment:
        name: E-WindowsServers
        resourceName: ${{ Server.ServerName }}
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - script: |
                echo ${{ Server.ServerName }}
```

[image]